# Can't install extensions "Failed to connect to magento-community port 443: Connection refused"

Tags: extensions, magento-1, installation

I am trying to install an extension (I have tried more than 1 and also checked version compatibility) but I keep getting this error:

> Failed to connect to magento-community port 443: Connection refused

An example extension key that this occurs on is:

`magento-community/ArtsOnIT_OfflineMaintenance`

Comment: are you using PHP 5.6? We had issues in the default ciphers there and our new servers for Connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you copied the extension key for Magento Connect version 1.0 which is [applicable for Magento CE 1.4.2.0 and earlier](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/7_-_magento_connect/differences_in_magento_connect_versions). Unfortunately you did not include which Magento version you are using. However, if it is CE 1.5 or later, try the extension key for Magento Connect version 2.0 – possibly in combination with the suggestion by Piotr.

Answer (score 2):

Just download the extensions manually, check over the code and unpack yourself:

http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php?ext=magento-community%2FArtsOnIT_OfflineMaintenance

Comment: This answer is wild-goose-chase free. You want the extension, just download it.

Answer (score 2):

While we did a workaround to address that, can you try to apply the patch https://gist.github.com/piotrekkaminski/9cf894ae14af660bcc96

or https://gist.github.com/piotrekkaminski/6bd1cd03f6d8f180af90

(depending on version) and see if it helps?

We've seen this problem on PHP 5.6 only earlier.